# Why can't I use a mask filter with my ImageView?

Tags: java, android, graphics

I am using a glow effect which works using `setMaskFilter` to blur the painted area:

```
public static Paint createGlowPaint(Context context, @ColorRes int baseColorKey) {
    float glowWidth = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.analog_blur_width);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor((Workarounds.getColor(context, baseColorKey) & 0xFFFFFF) | 0x40000000);
    paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(glowWidth, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(glowWidth);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    return paint;
}
```

This is used along with custom vector graphics to do the drawing of the blur and then the drawing of the hands of my watch face. This is all packaged up into a `Drawable` so that I can use it in more than one place. Or so I thought! It turns out that even though this works fine when painted directly onto the top-level canvas, when I try to use `ImageView#setImageDrawable` to set the exact same `Drawable` onto an `ImageView`, the filter no longer gets applied.

You can see how this sort of blur looks:

[image: Image showing the effect]

Using it with an `ImageView`, now you get a hard edge instead:

[image: Image showing a failure to apply the filter]

What is going on here?

*Edit for additional info:*

Code that does the drawing, i.e. is using the glow paint:

```
public abstract class Hands extends Drawable {
    // ... lots of other cruft

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        //todo could probably precompute more in onBoundsChange
        Rect bounds = getBounds();
        int centerX = bounds.centerX();
        int centerY = bounds.centerY();

        if (watchMode.isInteractive()) {
            handGlowPath.reset();
            handGlowPath.addPath(hourHand.getPath());
            handGlowPath.addPath(minuteHand.getPath());
            handGlowPath.addCircle(centerX, centerY, centreRadius, Path.Direction.CCW);
            canvas.drawPath(handGlowPath, handGlowPaint);
        }

        hourHand.draw(canvas);
        minuteHand.draw(canvas);

        if (watchMode.isInteractive()) {
            secondHand.draw(canvas);
            if (hasThirds()) {
                thirdHand.draw(canvas);
            }
        }

        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, centreRadius, centrePaint.getPaint());
    }
```

Code that puts the drawable into the `ImageView`:

```
class PreviewListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    // ... other methods for the list adapter

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView instanceof ViewHolder) {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView;
        } else {
            holder = new ViewHolder(getContext(), inflater.inflate(R.layout.config_list_item, parent, false));
        }

        // Deliberately making this a square.
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams holderLayoutParams =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(parent.getWidth(), parent.getWidth());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams viewLayoutParams =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(parent.getWidth(), parent.getWidth());
        if (position == 0) {
            holderLayoutParams.height += 20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            viewLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM;
        } else if (position == getCount() - 1) {
            holderLayoutParams.height += 20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            viewLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP;
        } else {
            viewLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        }
        holder.setLayoutParams(holderLayoutParams);
        holder.view.setLayoutParams(viewLayoutParams);

        holder.image.setImageDrawable(items[position].drawable);
        holder.text.setText(items[position].labelText);
        return holder;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the code where you apply this paint to the ImageView?

Comment: @GilMoshayof Done, though maybe it isn't what you think, because there is never a place where I apply a paint to the ImageView. The paint is used when drawing the Drawable, and the Drawable is added to the ImageView.

Comment: yes, this is what I meant. This drawable works fine until you use it with an ImageView?

Comment: @GilMoshayof Yeah. The first screenshot is painting straight onto the surface provided by the WatchFaceService.Engine. The second screenshot is what I get on the config activity. I refactored out the drawing code so that it can be used in both places, but the result is different for some reason. I'm sure it's some property of the surface being drawn onto when it's an ImageView, but reading the code of the WatchFaceService doesn't make it any clearer.

Comment: try setting the imageview's layer type to software:  holder.image.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

Comment: @GilMoshayof Bingo, want to post that as an answer? :)

Comment: I posted this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from API 14, `BlurMaskFilters` are not supported when hardware acceleration is enabled.

To work around this, set your `ImageView's` layer type to software:

```
 holder.image.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```